# Website button that launch a game on client's PC

Tags: php, button, web

I'm a part of a business and we develop games, and host server of it (publisher) and we are in need to make a button on our website that when a customer clicks it, it will start off the game on his computer (in case he/she has the files and the game installed).

My questions are, how do we do that? What language do we need to program this on? Any libraries it should use? How do I get the location of the files as many people install it in different places then the default directory of the setup, how to retrieve the location of the folder and execution file on every computer?

Short note; This is for Windows OS, after we finish doing developing our Mac client, we will implement this for Mac as well.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not somewhere where people do your code for you. We are here as a community to fix issues, and show you through things. We are not however free developers.

Comment: @jshthornton Clearly the person asking the question needs advice on how to get started and isn't looking for complete code for a solution.  Relax.  This question is very much on-topic for Stack Overflow, and is within the rules outlined on the help page.

Comment: @Brad: while I've up voted your answer, note that while the subject is on topic, the explicit request to "*...refer me to somewhere I can study on it*" makes it explicitly off topic (requesting an external resource). Care to edit the question? Then I can, perhaps, remove my close-vote.

Comment: @DavidThomas Edit made.  And, for what it's worth the core of this question had nothing to do with looking for an external resource.  To me, it's clear that the person asking this question was simply trying to be polite.  It's common for newer folks to not want to take the time of those they feel are knowledgeable, but the core of the question was fine.

Comment: @DavidThomas Never mind, apparently I was wrong in my interpretation.  Now he's asking for off-site resources.

Comment: Well, I rescinded my vote based on your edit (and can't vote again, apparently) :(

Comment: I'm sorry if I was misunderstood, I want to research about it and I don't think anyone here can provide me article of this whole subject written in Stack Exchange.
I understood what Brad wrote as an answer but it's not much of a clear one as I need to make a small research of how to create new protocol header and to study how the core of it actually works, how it functions in order to provide my boss this system feature in the best way possible, with no security holes and anything that can risk both the business nor the customers using it.
This subject is sort of complicates

Comment: it involves more than just coding, it's networking, browser integration (plugin perhaps) and more on the client side I assume.

Comment: There is no networking, and no browser plugin needed. When the browser can't handle a protocol, it asks the OS what can, and executes that handler.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, this is done with a custom protocol handler (referred to as the "scheme" of the URL).

Your application can register itself as the handler of `yourcompany://`.  Once this is done, your browser will launch the program that can handle this (your game launcher).  Your program can then parse the URL to figure out what to do.

For example, you might have on a page `yourcompany://somegame/?network-game-id=12345`, which could tell your launcher to launch the game named `somegame.exe` with the parameters to automatically join the multiplayer game in progress with the ID of 12345.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps me a lot!!!
Is there any article you can point out that I can study and research more about it?

Comment: @CoreIncLTD That's really all there is to it.  I don't know what to suggest to you beyond what I've specified in my answer.  I guess since you're asking about Windows at the moment, here's the docs:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx